# How do I build a DC time out circuit that stays off until power is toggled?

Tags: dc, timer, toggle-switch

My girlfriend bought an LED faucet that is actuated when you turn the water on and is powered by a battery pack of 4 AA batteries (2 wire out).

[image: led faucet example]

However, when the water is turned off, the slope of the faucet is rarely sufficient to overcome the surface tension and the faucet remains on.   How can I build a timeout circuit such that the faucet turns off after being lit for 5-10 minutes and stays off unless water is fully cleared from the faucet and then the faucet is turned on again?

A friend of mine recommended a 555 chip, but after looking into it it seem the faucet would just turn off after 5 min, then turn back on 5 min later and keep cycling indefinitely.

I tried searching this site and came across [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61877/shutdown-controller-for-raspberry-pi-in-a-car/62441#62441) that seem similar, but can't figure out how to deal with the fact that the activation of the circuit would work more like a toggle switch than a push button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a 555 would do the job.  The 555 can work in a number of ways - the one you are looking for is called "Monostable".  This triggers once on the press of a button and turns itself off after a certain amount of time.  Nothing happens until you press the button again.

Replacing the button with a capacitor effectively gives you a single press of the button at power-on time and nothing after that.

Something along the lines of (though I haven't tested it of course):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fALlzq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- R1 and C2 define how long it stays turned on for (around 363 seconds that should be with those values).
- C1 and R2 cause a delay on the trigger rising at power-on (you may want to increase C1 slightly for more initial delay).
- The 555 when activated turns on Q2 which in turn turns on Q1 which allows the power to flow to the LEDs.

By the way, this circuit was inspired by: http://555-timer-circuits.uk/operation/one-shot2.html

Comment: Thanks, I think the C1 / R2 circuit explains how to make a trigger that turns off.  However I have some concerns:  the switch(water) and the LEDs are in-line and there's really no way for me to separate them from one another, but if I understand the diagram, the LEDs are suppose to be between Q1 and Q2, while the switch is between Q1 and ground correct?

Comment: Forgive me - I omitted that kind of detail from the circuit. I have updated the circuit to show where the existing switch unit would connect (between the battery and the 555 circuit) and where the LEDs connect (plus whatever drive / current control circuit they have).

Comment: No worries, I'm sure it would have been obvious to anyone who has taken an EE course; the wikipedia page on BJTs is very dense and full of argots.