# Is there anything wrong with this particular timer circuit utilizing 555?

Tags: timer, 555

I created following simple timer circuit for one shot operation.
[image]

My expectation is it to give 5v as output (for D RELAY and SP RELAY) for certain number of seconds/minutes soon as it got powered-on. Time interval to be selected using the rotary switch (bottom side).

I created this circuit by taking [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/161088/128918). Additional things I added are voltage regular part with AMS1117-5.0 and various resister series selectable using rotary switch combined with 1000uF capacitor.

I tested timer part, excluding voltage regular, on breadboard and worked good. Then created PCB with SMD components (except 1000uF and 22uF capacitors and BS170 MOSFET. Those are through hole ones).

I am using a wall adapter having 8.4v for Vcc.

The problem is the timer is not working at all. It even does not give HIGH when I tested it using multimeter put across OUT pin of 555 and GND.

I am not yet good at electronics and took around one day to build the PCB!

Please help me to identify the problem in this circuit.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That schematic works fine on breadboard, but not on a PCB?  We therefore need to see the PCB.

Comment: @HandyHowie Not entire schematic. Voltage regular part was not in my breadboard testing because AMS1117 is available only in SO223 package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concept (guessing here, because you have not precisely explained what you expect to happen) appears to be wrong- opening the ground on the x1117 will not give you 0V, it will give you almost the input voltage.

When the MOSFET switches on it will *drop* to 5V.

But your timer not working is another thing and may involve some issue with construction or some other difference between your breadboard and the PCB (including a fried chip, but that's probably unlikely without a bit of drama such as it getting very hot).

Measure the voltages on each pin- pin 5 should measure about 2/3 Vcc and pins 2,4,8 should measure about Vcc. Make sure the rotary switch is wired correctly. And try triggering the timer by momentarily shorting C1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added my expection just below to diagram.
"And try triggering the timer by momentarily shorting C1". I tried, then it started to give 4.97v as output of voltage regulator. Then stopped after certain time period, varies on rotary switch selection.

Comment: Your input dv/dt may be too slow to trigger the timer. Try increasing C1 to 100nF.

Comment: Opening the ground *will* give 0V across the output connector, however.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I replaced C1 capacitor to have 100nF and it started to work!!
However 555 stopped working after few more tests. Assuming IC might have damaged while soldering, I replaced that NE555. Now circuit works good so far. Thanks for the help.
I will mark this answer as selected one.

Comment: @immibis, regarding your comment. Is it bad for circuit someway?

Comment: It's not inherently bad.

Comment: @Junaid No, just replying to the sentence that said "opening the ground will not give you 0V, it will give you almost the input voltage". That sentence suggests this is a wrong way to do things, but it is pretty normal actually (depending on what is connected to the output connector, in this case a relay I assume).